# how to read unicode characters in data stage that is NON NLS

Tags: oracle10g, datastage

I am having Unicode characters present in a column with varchar2 as datatype. Table is present in Oracle Db. Oracle has AL32UTF8 set. But my data stage engine is installed without NLS. Is there any way I can read these Unicode characters without installing NLS?

Comment: I am able to read these Unicode characters via SQL developer correctly. But while reading it thru a Oracle plugin in datastage , I am getting "?" in place of these Unicode characters.